# FCM Token dosent save in Database when user clicks "Allow" on notifications

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed a app that is in the App Store right now. However before launch I tested the app with my iPhone and the FCM token got registered in the database. However now as users start to use the app, I can see that FCM token dosen't save in the database? I asked my friend to test it out, and he neither gets the FCM token stored in the database.

And as a result of this, notifications are not displayed (because the function dosen't have a phone to send the notification to).

Can anyone figure this out?
(I have tried to resolve this issue for the past days, cant seem to catch where its gone wrong)

Code in my first ViewController, that users arrive to after signing up.

```
func registerForRemoteNotifications() {
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        if let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
             Database.database().reference().child("profile/" + userUid + "/fcmToken").setValue(fcmToken)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that 'FCM token' is only sent to the db when a user is logged in, So the issue is coming when user opens app for first time when he isnt logged in.

Solution is:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue("fcmToken", forKey: fcmToken)
    }
```

- later on fetch the token from userDefaults

  let deviceToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"fcmToken") as? String ?? "not found"

  to send it to server just after user gets logged in.

Comment: also make sure your development & production certificates are uploaded on firebase console for push notifications.

Comment: Ahhhh thanks, didnt notice that. Its not the licences and certificates, but it has to be when user opens app for the first time. Should i remove my `didRecieveRegistrationToken` and replace it with yours? or add UserDefault to mine? Also what do you mean with  " later on fetch the token from userDefaults

let deviceToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"fcmToken") as? String ?? "not found"    "

Comment: @MattGilbert That line returns "not found" if UserDefaults returns nil for fcmToken. [See coalescing](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-nil-coalescing-operator) for details.

Comment: try printing out the fcm token in the above my method before storing into userDefaults

Comment: i took the didRecieveRegistrationToken in AppDelegate, and copied your code. And also fetched the token from userDefaults...

Comment: yes 'didRecieveRegistrationToken' this should be in Appdelegate. is it working now?

Comment: When i have didRecieveRegistrationToken in AppDelegate, i get error in "Feedviewcontroller" where i ask for user permission to send notifications, that states something like  `does not conform to protocol, your missing didRecieveRegistrationToken in FeedViewController`, but i have it in AppDelegate?? Why is it saying this

Comment: this is the error `FeedViewController does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token.`

Comment: also ask the permission in the didFinishLaunchingOptions in AppDelegate file then if will work fine.